# Nvidia Optimus on 20.04: switching to Intel GPU works on Ubuntu Mate, but not on Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: nvidia-optimus, ubuntu-mate, 20.04, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-prime

I am trying to revive an old Lenovo Ideapad Z360 laptop using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. This laptop has an integrated Intel GPU and a discrete Nvidia GPU, as follows:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [GeForce 310M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GT218M [GeForce 310M]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia
```

**On Ubuntu Mate 20.04, I am able to switch from the Nvidia GPU to the Intel GPU just fine.** I can do this using the panel icon (mate-optimus); or using the terminal (prime-select); or using the Nvidia application (nvidia-settings). They all work, and the desktop loads just fine after I logout and login back again. The "on demand" option doesn't work --- mate-optimus' github states that "NVIDIA On-Demand (known as PRIME Render Offload) will require the NVIDIA 435 drivers", so I guess this excludes my GPU (which uses NVIDIA 340 drivers) ---, but I am ok with that. I am happy being able to switch between the Intel and Nvidia GPUs when needed. On Ubuntu Mate 20.04, this works just fine.

**However, on Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome), switching to the Intel GPU doesn't work!!**

First thing I noticed is that the "PRIME Profiles" menu section was not available in the Nvidia application (nvidia-settings). I was able to fix that by installing the nvidia-prime package (which came pre-installed in Ubuntu Mate, but not in Ubuntu Gnome).

However, when I try to switch to the Intel GPU, I am not able to log back into the desktop after I logout (it loops back to the gdm3 greeter). If I reboot when the Intel GPU is selected, than I get a black screen. In order to fix that, I have to either switch back to the Nvidia GPU (using prime-select), or remove all nvidia packages (and use the nouveau driver instead).

**So my question is: Why does it work on Ubuntu Mate, but not on Ubuntu Gnome?**

Answer (score 0):

I have an old Alienware 11Mx3 with Optimus on Nvidia 310. It is running awesome on Nvidia 345.21. I can switch smoothly back and forth... My trick is to install opting out of "third party drivers and ...". That gives me a closed-driver clean installation.

From there and after logging in, I update, upgrade and without rebooting perform the installation of the nvidia-driver-435. After rebooting, it all works.

It all works out nice and believe me I had lost all hope for Optimus. Before, my Alienware was collecting dust in its bag... now it goes with me everywhere. I am running Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 LTS and it's buttery smooth in Intel & Nvidia mode...

Comment: Thank you for your reply! :)

I assume you meant 435.21 (not 345.21). Still, I am confused....

The GeForce 310 GPU is not listed on Nvidia's website as one of the supported products for driver 435.21. The recommended driver for that GPU is 340.108. Why are using 435.21 then? Anyway, I guess it is worth a try... I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: I purged nvidia-340 and nvidia-opencl-icd-340, then installed nvidia-driver-435, then rebooted. The system booted into gnome using the intel driver. The additional drivers tab did not display any drivers. The nvida-settings app was pretty much empty: the only availabe menu was "PRIME Profiles". I went to a terminal, did prime-select nvidia, logged-out and logged back in. Tried glxgears, but it was at 60 fps. So my guess is it didn't work.

Comment: For me with ubuntu 20.04.1 and nvidia 450 render offload works with manual launch applications with __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia
But I have no "On-Demand" entry in nvidia-settings which says "PRIME: is it supported? no"
Any idea to get On-Demand working ?

Answer (score 0):

I was wrestling with this problem as well and I discovered by accident you need to blacklist the nouveau kernel module. Once I did that, the machine boots up properly in dual monitor and in laptop only mode.

I also discovered nouveau was a problem with the lambda stack for machine learning on another system. You had to blacklist nouveau in the Linux kernel and grub.

[Blacklisting nouveau instructions found here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-blacklist-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux)

Short form:

```
sudo bash -c "echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
sudo bash -c "echo options nouveau modeset=0 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
```

Blacklisting nouveau in grub:

1. edit /etc/default/grub
2. modify GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to include nomodeset. For example:

   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodset"
3. run update-grub
4. reboot

Comment: oops, updating the answer